# Double Pivot in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have the following set of data that I am trying to do a cross table / double pivot on. Not sure the best description for that. What i want to do is sum each product (column a) over the next 2 columns (b and c) with the values of column D. Running into some issues with going about that.

[Left Side is current raw data - Right is End Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTqvH.png)

I tried creating some pivots but was unable to achieve my end result there

Comment: Do not post images of code or data. Instead, [edit] your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and the expected output as text (formatted using a markdown). Also, if you have made attempts at writing code then you should share what you have tried and the issues/errors with your code.

Answer (score 3):

Just `PIVOT` once and then add the values to get the total:

```sql
SELECT product_name,
       COALESCE(gross_cdc, 0) AS gross_cdc,
       COALESCE(gross_other, 0) AS gross_other,
       COALESCE(returns_cdc, 0) AS returns_cdc,
       COALESCE(returns_other, 0) AS returns_other,
       COALESCE(gross_cdc, 0)
         + COALESCE(gross_other, 0)
         + COALESCE(returns_cdc, 0)
         + COALESCE(returns_other, 0) AS total
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  SUM(doses)
  FOR (sales_category, sales_type) IN (
    ('CDC',   'GROSS')   AS gross_cdc,
    ('OTHER', 'GROSS')   AS gross_other,
    ('CDC',   'RETURNS') AS returns_cdc,
    ('OTHER', 'RETURNS') AS returns_other
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (product_name, sales_category, sales_type, doses) AS
  SELECT 'Product1', 'OTHER', 'GROSS',    15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Product1', 'OTHER', 'RETURNS',  -5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Product2', 'CDC',   'GROSS',    20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Product2', 'OTHER', 'GROSS',    25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Product2', 'OTHER', 'RETURNS',  -5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Product3', 'CDC',   'GROSS',    30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Product3', 'OTHER', 'GROSS',    25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Product3', 'OTHER', 'RETURNS', -10 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PRODUCT_NAME | GROSS_CDC | GROSS_OTHER | RETURNS_CDC | RETURNS_OTHER | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | 0 | 15 | 0 | -5 | 10 |
| Product2 | 20 | 25 | 0 | -5 | 40 |
| Product3 | 30 | 25 | 0 | -10 | 45 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dYXZ7yqH)